# Authentication fail error while loading an applet to a test sim card

Tags: applet, javacard, sim-toolkit

While loading an applet to a sim card, i get Authentication failure error. Because of the limited try of sim card key, i wonder this error means the card is blocked, or nor?

Comment: Depends, what status word do you receive?

Comment: the word is just like 'authentication failure'. What happens when the card is blocked?

Comment: The ISO 7816 status word (SW) is normally printed in binary (two bytes), e.g. `6982`.

Comment: There are many reasons why a load application could fail. The status word will give you a hint (maybe), but these values depend on card manufacturers.

Comment: @takumar they depend on card manufacturers *unless they have been clearly defined by the standard that defines the APDU's, such as Global Platform*. ISO 7816-4, which "defines" most APDU's is however not much help, I grant you that. Worst specification *ever*.

Answer (score 0):

Before loading an applet, you must to do an authentication with the Card Manager on Smartcard. In order to do the authentication, you have to know the card issuer keys.
There is a limit number of attempt to authenticate. Usually this number is 10. If you exceed this limit, the card will block. Once you do a successfully authentication this limit is reset.

Comment: Actually, i successfully load an applet to the same card before. When i want to load the other applet, i get this error. is it necessary to configure the card again and i get this error more than 10 times. Is it possible to repair the card?

Comment: The amount of attempts is specific to the implementation. The problem with limiting the number of attempts is that it makes the card susceptible to denial of service attacks. Not blocking the card will however open the card up to side channel attacks (brute forcing keys is normally not feasible). Normally, when the card manager is blocked, then the game is over, unless the card has a proprietary unblocking mechanism implemented. Check the user manual of the card you are trying to use.